# how to have sidemenu inside UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, side-menu

How to have sidemenu inside UITabBarController ?

previous integrated side menu with SingleViewController,

But how same behaviors will have into `UITabBarController` with sidemenu?

Same as like naukri / twitter app.

Comment: Ray Wenderlich has a tutorial to do exactly this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1005187-how-to-create-your-own-slide-out-panel-navigation

Comment: Looks like singleviewcontroller